# New Object variations

Tags: c++, class, initialization, new-operator

This is a very newbie question, but something completely new to me. In my code, and everywhere I have seen it before, new objects are created as such...

```
MyClass x = new MyClass(factory);
```

However, I just saw some example code that looks like this...

```
MyClass x(factory);
```

Does that do the same thing?

Comment: That first line won't compile. Which C++ book are you learning from? Obviously you're coming from Java or C# or some similar language. You do need a good book to learn C++.

Comment: Attention to detail is a good idea in programming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not at all.

The first example uses dynamic memory allocation, i.e., you are allocating an instance of `MyClass` on the heap (as opposed to the stack).  You would need to call `delete` on that pointer manually or you end up with a memory leak.  Also, `operator new` returns a pointer, not the object itself, so your code would not compile.  It needs to change to:

```
MyClass* x = new MyClass(factory);
```

The second example allocated an instance of `MyClass` on the stack.  This is very useful for short lived objects as they will automatically be cleaned up when the leave the current scope (and it is fast; cleaning up the stack involves nothing more than incrementing or decrementing a pointer).

This is also how you would implement the [Resource Acquisition is Initialization pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization), more commonly referred to as RAII.  The destructor for your type would clean up any dynamically allocated memory, so when the stack allocated variable goes out of scope any dynamically allocated memory is cleaned up for you without the need for any outside calls to `delete`.

Answer (score 2):

No. When you use `new`, you create objects off the heap that you must then delete later. In addition, you really need `MyClass*`. The other form creates an object on the stack that will be automatically destroyed at end of scope.

Comment: That would make sense. In the example everything with the code was packed into the main() function, so destroying it at the end of the scope would be fine. Thank you!